# HTML - `display: flex` prevents deletion of content from a contentEditable element when deleting from the end

Tags: html, css

I have this simple `contentEditable` paragraph element:

```
<p contenteditable="true">
   hello-world
   <span contenteditable="false">LABEL 1</span>
   middle text 
   <span contenteditable="false">LABEL 2</span>
   final text
</p>
```

This works great. I can add and delete anything. But if I add this CSS,

```
p {
    display: flex;
}
```

I can no longer delete content when deleting from the last character using backspace key. See this GIF for better explanation:

[image: display-flex]

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/d9zutyak/1/ (Try deleting from the last character with backspace. LABEL 2 won't delete. Then remove the CSS and then try again. LABEL 2 deletes now).

Why does this `display` property affect the way deletion happens and how can I fix this?

---

I am using 5.3.2679.70 (Stable channel) (x86_64) Vivaldi browser (Chromium engine)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the situation you describe. Running your fiddle if I remove the display: flex I get the same behavior - deleting from the end deletes the whole of one of those LABELs as a chunk which I think we'd expect given they are not editable. Are you certain that removing that CSS display changes editing behavior?

Comment: @AHaworth Keep the CSS and try deleting from the end with backspace. You won't be able to delete past the span.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now (on Edge/Windows 10). It doesn't have the same behavior on Firefox (where the whole LABEL is deleted on a backspace and you can carry on backspacing).

Comment: actually, it is not editable anymore when you set the `display` to `flex`

Comment: @KiaBoluki what browser/OS are you on? If you run the snippet in my answer is it not editable? I see it as editable, (on e.g. Edge/Chrome Windows10) apart from the different behaviors described.

Comment: @AHaworth OS : Windows 10 and Browser: Chrome

Comment: @AHaworth If the span is the last item, it will be uneditable

Comment: @AHaworth check this out : https://jsfiddle.net/KiaBoluki/fkcgt8uh/6/

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an exact explanation for the behavior - apart from anything else Edge/Chrome and Firefox behave differently at least on my Windows 10.

However, thinking about what flex (and grid shows the same behaviors) does, I realise I don't know exactly what it is intended that it should do when some text is not within its own element.

A workaround seems to be to make sure there is no text that is not within a child of p.

This snippet wraps all such text in spans. It appears that they still inherit the contenteditable attribute from their parent and deletion from the end does not get 'stuck' at a non-editable element which just gets deleted as a chunk.

```css
p {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<p contenteditable="true"><span>hello-world</span><span contenteditable="false">LABEL 1</span><span>middle text </span><span contenteditable="false">LABEL 2</span><span> final text</span></p>
```